# How data is transferred to further process by using a multicast address

Tags: networking, multicast

I am new to networking and I need to know how a multicast address is used in sending packets.

Will it use a MAC address or an IP to send the data?

Comment: Mulitcast is a network protocol (OSI level 3), and uses IP. The MAC address is used for the link layer protocol (OSI level 2, e.g. Ethernet). However the level 2 multicast is necessary to relay the level 3 multicast. See [http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/general-networking/107-network-multicast.html](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/general-networking/107-network-multicast.html).